Advertising in meat-space: posters on campuses
Riffing on my previous efforts to make a t-shirt and the need to attract more users, would it be possible for StackExchange to fund a poster run across various campuses?
List of possible campuses (edit as needed):

Wilfred Laurier: Seanny123
University of Waterloo: Seanny123
University of Ottawa: Seanny123
Carleton University: Seanny123
McMaster University: Seanny123
Laurentian University: Seanny123
Western University: Seanny123

Update
We've rebooted and I've finished the designs. Let me know what you think!

This is extra relevant with the new school year approaching fast.

Here is my first design, with a slogan similar to the one on the t-shirts. However, I'm also partial to the slogan suggested by @mfloren.

With the slogan suggested my @mfloren:


It sounds like a cool idea to me. I imagine the main work would be designing such a poster. After that, printing off something, say in A3, would not be too difficult. And then there's the challenge of working out where to put such a poster to catch the eyes of interested parties.

Often there are specific locations where student/study associations can hang up their posters about activities, and sometime the study associations have their own bulletin boards. Would think these are the most suitable.

Love the idea! We may want to address two different audiences depending on the school (and even location in the school). For instance, I would feel hesitant hanging up such a poster in our Psych PhD poster area because these are the folks who may answer questions (more than ask them). Perhaps slogans more along the lines of "ask tough questions, explore interesting answers, help out others, etc" may be a better fit for such places?
